# Probability Notations and Continuity

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-topology

I started working on probability theory and there is something I am confused with.

Consider a transition function p on a countable and compact space $X$ that is $p(x^\prime|x)$.

How can I understand the difference between $p(dx^\prime|x,a)$ and $p(x^\prime|x,a)$? In particular do $p(dx^\prime|x,a)$ and $p(x^\prime|x,a)$ coincide for countable space?

In addition, assuming weak continuity or continuity holds on $p(dx^\prime|x,a)$, how does it apply to $p(x^\prime|x,a)$? My guess is, if it coincides then the (weak) continuity assumption applies as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Déjà-vu. Did you post this before?

Comment: I modified my last post in order to make it clearer as I didn't have any answer.

Comment: It may help to provide some context. What is a transition function?

Comment: A transition function is defined as follows. $p:X\times A \to P(X)$ where P(X) is a probability distribution on $X$

Comment: Is that the entire definition? 1) that doesn’t seem to match what you’ve written 2) That sounds something like what is sometimes called a Markov kernel in the literature, though your definition is rather unrestrictive

Comment: This is indeed related to Markov kernel. Each transition is markov as it only depends on your current state

Comment: Could you edit the question and make the context and notation clear? It is hard to discern what is happening here, the two issues I had remain.

Comment: I don't really know how I can edit the question. I juste started working on this subject so I am not very familiar with the context. Can you specify where you have issues so that I can maybe clarify?

Comment: You said $p$ has domain $X\times A$ and wrote $p(x’\mid x,a)$ and also $p(dx’\mid x,a)$; these don’t agree. You also didn’t specify what $A$ is, but I’m assuming it’s a $\sigma$ algebra, in which case, you should really use $\mathcal A$. A Markov kernel is defined as follows. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces. The map $\mu:\Omega \times \mathcal E\to [0,1]$ is a Markov kernel means $\mu(\cdot,B)$ is measurable for $B\in \mathcal E$ and $\mu(\omega,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ for $\omega\in \Omega$.

Comment: In the above context, the notation $\mu(\omega,dx)$ makes sense. If you really want to, you could write it as $\mu(dx\mid \omega)$. Perhaps you ask if $\mu(\{x\}\mid\omega)$ is the same as $\mu(dx\mid \omega)$. The answer is not really. Consider $E_\omega f(X) = \int f(x)\mu(dx\mid\omega)$. We do not write, as a convention, $E_\omega =\int f(x)\mu(\{x\}\mid \omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help